# Bottle keeps turning itself off?

Tags: python, web-server

I don't have this problem on my laptop or VMs I use at work.

I use bottle for my web framework and my python scripts seem to just stop running, requiring me to start them again. I always use a `screen` for all my Bottle work (on my laptop, VMs, RPi).

The controller on my RPi looks something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from bottle import route, run, template, debug, post, request
import MySQLdb

@route('/batch')
def batch():
    ...

debug(True)
run(host='0.0.0.0', port='8080', reloader=True)
```

Any idea why the script just stops running?

Comment: How much memory / swap does the Pi use when everything's started up ? Are there any messages in dmesg ?

Comment: `free -m` shows 12M free of 232, and 99M free of swap. How would I tell if there are messages in dmesg related to bottle? If i execute `dmesg` I receive a bunch of notices about how my temperature probes don't respond to CONVERT_TEMP and take up all the screen. If I do `dmesg | grep bottle` or `dmesg | grep python` or `dmesg | grep py` I receive no results (my controller is named controller.py)

Comment: When does it stop running? After n number of connections after a specific time, is all ways repeatable?

Comment: Have you looked in `/var/log/messages` as well?

Comment: @rob I generally make one or two connections to it, and if I check back perhaps 10 minutes later it is gone. Always.

Comment: @Fred I get the same results in dmesg: notices about the temperature broves and CONVERT_TEMP, and the greps don't provide any information either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [first result](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/bottlepy/wbgfiLKdoLg) on Google...:

> I ripped out my home alarm system central box and replaced it with a Raspberry Pi running a small bottle app about 9 months ago, interfacing to a PiFace board. I found the same problem as you. Debugged it for a while but decided it was some odd bug in the generic python wsgi server. Eventually I switched to bjoern server and that problem went away but I found that after some time my app would creep to and stay with high cpu. Then I switched to meinheld server and my small but multi-threaded web app has been running for many months on end, without any issue, and with total CPU load around 5%.
>
> Changing the server is surprising easy. Just sudo apt-get python-pip, sudo pip install meinheld, and then add server="meinheld" to your bottle.run().
>
> BTW, I benchmarked all 17 of the servers which bottle supports natively and found bjoern and meinheld to be significantly the best performing. For my app, they return requests/sec nearly 10 times the rate of the default python wsgi server.

I'll try this and report back.